# How does The Alpha 21264 Microprocessor checkpoint the register map?

Tags: cpu-architecture, processor, alpha-cpu-architecture

In the paper describing The Alpha 21264 Microprocessor [here](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Emilom/cis501-Fall09/papers/Alpha21264.pdf),

> The register map is backed up to the state before the last squashed instruction using the saved map state. The map state for each in-flight instruction is maintained, so it is easily restored.

The microprocessor can have 80 in-flight instructions, does this mean there will be 80 checkpoints of the register map (for each instruction) ? If so, this would require a large amount of storage dedicated just for checkpoint recovery. My question is, is the entire register map stored, which takes up a lot of space, or is some other mechanism used instead of storing all the maps which will take up a smaller amount of space?

Comment: This is likely not unique to Alpha; most out-of-order exec CPUs have a RAT (register allocation table), so they all need some way to roll back to a previous state on interrupts or mis-speculation.  I'd guess most use a pretty similar mechanism, but I don't know the details of how it's done.

Comment: @PeterCordes I found the answer to this. In the Alpha 21264, instead of having a table which is used as a LUT to figure out the physical register, the table contains information if a particular physical register is mapped to a logical register. The logical register mapping is found using a CAM search. The checkpoint for this would just contain the valid bits at the time of instruction decode. This exploits the fact that, after decoding, the mapping will not be freed until the instruction in the ROB is committed and only the valid bits change from the time between decode and commit.

Comment: You can post an answer to your question, not just a comment, then people can upvote that as well.  (And you'll have room to link to the source you found for that info.)